AAPT2 error when assembling release React Native Android on gitlab runner with docker executor
I set up a gitlab runner that using docker executor on my mac m1 to perform cicd pipeline for a React Native 0.74.2 project, but faced an error with AAPT2 when trying to run command ./gradlew assembleRelease. I will show the error at the end. Below are my setting of my project and docker:
Project build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.0')
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }

    // Load properties from local.properties
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withInputStream { stream ->
            localProperties.load(stream)
        }
    }

    // Set Java home
    def javaHome = localProperties.getProperty('java17.dir', System.getenv('JAVA_HOME'))
    if (javaHome) {
        System.setProperty('org.gradle.java.home', javaHome)
        println "Java Home: ${javaHome}"
    } else {
        throw new GradleException("Java home not found. Please set JAVA_HOME environment variable or specify java17.dir in local.properties.")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"


App build.gradle:
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    dev: ".env",
    pro: ".env.pro",
    anothercustombuild: ".env",
]

react {
    /* Hermes Commands */
    def hermesEndPoint
    if (OperatingSystem.current().name.toLowerCase().contains(OperatingSystem.LINUX.getFamilyName().toLowerCase())) {
        hermesEndPoint = "linux64-bin/hermesc"
    } else if (OperatingSystem.current().name.toLowerCase().contains(OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.getFamilyName().toLowerCase())) {
        hermesEndPoint = "win64-bin/hermesc.exe"
    } else {
        hermesEndPoint = "osx-bin/hermesc"
    }
    hermesCommand = "node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermesc/" + hermesEndPoint
    println("hermesEndPoint: ${hermesEndPoint}")
}

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.dockercicd"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId env.get("ANDROID_APP_ID")
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode project.env.get("ANDROID_VERSION_CODE")?.toInteger() ?: 1
        versionName env.get("ANDROID_VERSION_NAME")
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.dockercicd"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "app_name", project.env.get("APP_NAME")
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        pro {
            dimension "environment"
            resValue "string", "app_name", project.env.get("APP_NAME")
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)


gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

The dockerfile to build image:
# Use the Node.js 18 base image for ARM architecture
FROM arm64v8/node:18

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    openjdk-17-jdk \
    libc6 \
    libstdc++6 \
    zlib1g \
    curl \
    unzip \
    ruby-full \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set JAVA_HOME environment variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-arm64
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# Install Android SDK
ENV ANDROID_HOME /usr/local/android-sdk
RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools \
    && curl -o sdk-tools.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-7583922_latest.zip \
    && unzip sdk-tools.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools \
    && mv ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest \
    && rm sdk-tools.zip \
    && yes | ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager --licenses \
    && ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-34" "build-tools;34.0.0"

# Set environment variables for Android SDK
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

# Ensure correct permissions for Android SDK and AAPT2
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/local/android-sdk

# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Yarn
RUN if ! yarn --version; then npm install -g yarn; fi

In my .gitlab-ci.yml file, there are two jobs. The first job is install dependencies, which is . The second one is releasing android apk. The error happened in the second job, at the command ./gradlew assembleRelease. That job look like this:
build_android:
  image: my-docker-hub/my-image:my-tag
  needs:
    - install_dependencies_android # This is the first job. Running fine.
  tags:
    - my-mac-tag
  stage: build
  script:
    - yarn add yarn-audit-fix -D --ignore-engines
    - yarn yarn-audit-fix
    - cd android
    - chmod +x ./gradlew
    - ./gradlew clean
    - cd ../
    - npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
    - cd android
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace

This is the error:
> Task :app:packageDevReleaseResources
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output:  
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #5: Unexpected error output:  
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #3: Unexpected error output:  
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #4: Unexpected error output:  
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #6: Unexpected error output:  
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #2: Unexpected error output:  
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output:  
> Task :app:mergeDevReleaseResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevReleaseResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > AAPT2 aapt2-8.5.0-11315950-linux Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
        This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevReleaseResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)> Task :app:parseDevReleaseLocalResources
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$MultipleTaskActionFailures: Multiple task action failures occurred:
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:229)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:162)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.PreCreateOutputParentsStep.execute(PreCreateOutputParentsStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureOutputsAfterExecutionStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:189)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.executeDelegate(ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.executeDelegate(ResolveIncrementalCachingStateStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.execute(AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.execute(AbstractResolveCachingStateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(AbstractCaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:289)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:331)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.lambda$execute$0(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationRef.with(CurrentBuildOperationRef.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:314)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47)
Cause 1: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable

As you can see, the error mentions Rosetta, but I don't quite understand how Rosetta involve in this while I'm using Docker Desktop and node 18 in arm architecture. I also don't know what's wrong with AAPT2 since this is the first time I have this kind of error. Also, the first time i tried to build React Native release on linux environment. My project is fine on my mac environment.
What I have tried so far:

Downgrading build tool in dockerfile to 33.
Switching to a lower version (7.4.2) of classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle').

None of those work.
Anyone have an idea? Please share!
Thanks for reading!

The same issue occurs to me in the Docker container and it is strange because AAPT2 works fine on my arm64 Mac.
UPD: You can try to use aapt from android-platform-frameworks-base for Ubuntu.
run:
apt install aapt

replace aapt and aapt2 files(for me in usr/bin) from android-sdk-tools-static-aarch64.zip
add the following code to gradle.properties:
android.aapt2FromMavenOverride=/usr/bin/aapt2


Sorry for late reply. Your approach did help with the current problem, but I'm still unable to assemble releases because another problem with react-native-screen. Something about "  rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2". I will make another question.

apt-get update && apt-get install -y libunwind-dev
dpkg --add-architecture amd64
apt-get update
apt-get install -y binutils:amd64
